# Continue or break the while loop

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, while-loop

Im trying to figure out how to keep while loop going for posts on another section in bootstrap columns or is there way to "break it" and then keep it going where it remained? First picture shows the while loop showing 5 posts the way i want. Picture below shows how i want the next 6 posts keep going vertically. Now im getting the posts to show but it starts from the first post and just duplicates them. [image][image]

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <?php

  $args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
   );

   $blogposts = new WP_Query($args);

  $i = 0;
   while($blogposts->have_posts()) {
   $blogposts->the_post();

   if ($i < 2) :
   ?>
   <div class="col-md-6">
   <?php else : ?>
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <?php endif; ?>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <div class="card border-0">
      <div class="card-picture">

        <img class="card-img" src="<?php echo 
      get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()); ?>" alt="Card image">

        <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column">
          <h5 class="card-title font-weight-bold"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
          <div class="mt-auto"><?php the_author(); ?> - <i class="fas fa- 
      clock"></i> - <?php the_time('d/m/Y')?></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
     </a>
   </div>

    <?php
     wp_reset_query();
   $i++;
    }

   ?>



    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-8">
        <?php
$args = array(
    'post-type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
);

$blogposts = new WP_Query($args);

while($blogposts->have_posts()) {
    $blogposts->the_post();


     ?>
          <div class="card-3">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
              <div class="col-md-5">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <img class="card-3-img" src="<?php echo 
    get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID()); ?>" 
    class="card-img-top h-100" 
    alt="...">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-7">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title-3"><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                </a>
                  <p class="card-text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                  <div class="mt-auto"><?php the_author(); ?> - <i class="fas 
 fa-clock"></i> - <?php the_time('d/m/Y')?></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <?php }
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to do it all inside one loop, and then test if i > 5 to perform the alternate function. Once you restart the query, it's going to start from the beginning.